# Setting precision in Decimal class Python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, floating-point-precision, floating

I just learned the Decimal class in Python, and I have some issues in modifying the precision of the decimal numbers. Code:

```
from decimal import *

def main() :
  getcontext().prec = 50
  print Decimal(748327402479023).sqrt()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  main()
```

The output:

```
27355573.51764029457632865944595074348085555311409538
1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948
```

Instead of showing 50 decimal digits, it shows 50 digits in total. Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:**

I am solving a problem which requires big floating point accuracy. That's why i have to use python. Now if the answer to the problem is for example 0.55, i should print 0.55 followed by 48 zeroes...

Comment: to print zeros use string formatting: ```print "{:.50f}".format(d)```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of doing it is to set `prec` much higher than you need, then use `round`. Python 3:

```
>>> getcontext().prec=100
>>> print(round(Decimal(748327402479023).sqrt(), 50))
27355573.51764029457632865944595074348085555311409538175920
>>> print(round(Decimal(7483).sqrt(), 50))
86.50433515148243713481567854198645604944135142208905
```

For Python 2, do:

```
>>> print Decimal(748327402479023).sqrt().quantize(Decimal('1E-50'))
27355573.51764029457632865944595074348085555311409538175920
```

The value for `prec` depends on how large your numbers are, but it has to be greater than `log10` of your number, or you will get a `decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context` exception.

Comment: Using round coverts the Decimal back to built-in floating type

Comment: I am solving a problem which requires big floating point accuracy. That's why i have to use python. Now if the answer to the problem is 0.55, i should print 0.55 followed by 48 zeroes...