# Changing order of decimal numbers causing differnet results

Tags: python

I'm learning Python. Maybe this is a silly mistake and not related to Python at all but appreciate some clarity.

I have the following code.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

expense = Decimal('10.00')
v = Decimal('93.93863013698630136986301369')
n = Decimal('46.90520547945205479452054796')
yearly_expense = Decimal('0')

vn = v + n

r1 = expense - yearly_expense + v + n
r2 = expense - yearly_expense + vn

print(r1)
print(r2)
```

When I execute I get

```bash
150.8438356164383561643835617
150.8438356164383561643835616
```

Note the last digits. Why the 2 numbers are different?

Comment: Add return of `decimal.getcontext()` to question, please.

Comment: Reproducible on Python 3.10.6, getcontext() returns `Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[Inexact, Rounded], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])` for me.

Comment: The default precision in the Decimal package is 28 digits. Your input values have 28 digits, and when you combine them the result needs 29 digits. So you're getting roundoff error at the end.

Comment: @kaya3, now set `decimal.getcontext().prec = 30` and try again :)

Comment: see also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting precision in Decimal class Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638005/setting-precision-in-decimal-class-python)

Comment: You are seeing the fact that with finite precision floating point arithmetic (with or without the `decimal` module addition is sometimes non-associative: `a + (b+c)` and `(a+b)+c` can differ due to round-off error. Changing the precision can take care of a specific instance, but won't change the general phenomenon.

Comment: You can also set the traps[Inexact] in your context to catch this as an exception.